# Zend Db Sql Where

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

Hi how can I do a query like this in zf2 with zend\db\sql?

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = $field AND data > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

In ZF2

```
$select = $this->sql->select();
$select->from(self::MYTABLE)
           ->where(array('fiels' => $field))
           ->where(array('data > ' => 'SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$lifetime.' SECOND'));
$statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
return $statement->execute()->current();
```

Comment: Try `'data' => new Expression('SUBDATE(......)')` using [`Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Predicate/Expression.php#L14)

Comment: Then it should be `where(new Expression('data > SUBDATE(...)'))` - not too secure on Zend\Db myself - am a lazy doctrine ass :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line

```
->where(array('data > ' => 'SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$lifetime.' SECOND'));
```

to

```
->where(array('data > ?' => 'SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$lifetime.' SECOND'));
```

From the code snippet, it's seen you had missed the place holder for the parameter(?), include a question mark, I had mentioned the existing line of code and the modified code for quick reference

Comment: Please provide reason of the problem when answering questions instead of just giving the solution. For example, why i need to add a question mark to that statement?

Answer (score 0):

There's no parameter there so it doesn't need to be an array. Assuming you know `$lifetime` is a safe, integer value, try:

```
 ->where('data > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$lifetime.' SECOND)');
```